# Get the history "text" of a past work item edit

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Say I make a work item in TFS.  Then I make a change and update the text in the History tab (then save).

Using the TFS API, how can I get that text?

I would have thought it would have been in the *History* string for last item in the *Revisions* collection on the work item.  (Because to set the string via the API you can use *History* on a normal work item.)  However, in the *Revisions* array, all the work items are showing up as having *History* empty.

Any ideas on how I can get this string?

Answer (score 4):

Check this blog post out:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronbjork/archive/2011/01/10/programmatically-reading-work-item-comments.aspx

It’s a simple operation, but it might not be clear at first unless you discover that you need to loop through the collection of Revisions of the work item in order to view those comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can get any of the basic tfs fields via [aaronbjork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5746174/57883)'s link and change it to use

`Field f = r.Fields.TryGetById(1);` or `Field f = r.Fields["Title"]`

- title = `1`
- description = `52`
- the list of names and Ids is in the `CoreField` [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.corefield.aspx) (only for non-custom fields)